# Removing commas from data imported from a text file

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

Please suggest a way to remove the trailing comma so I can plot the following data;

```
data = 
  {{0., 0.,}, {10000., 0.,}, {20000., 1.,}, {1.*10^6, 4963.,}, {1.01*10^6, 4641.,}
```

Comment: It's entirely unclear what your issue is. Just delete the comma... then use `ListPlot`. Have you read the docs? If that's all in a `String` make that clear.

Comment: I have around 1000. data ponts, so it is hard to remove all commas.

Comment: What format is your data in? Is it a `String`? Is it in a `List`? How'd you get the data into Mathematica in the first place? There are so many things we don't know about your data. I'm sure it's a trivial fix but I don't know what your problem is.

Comment: {1.*10^6,?} why this elements does not have y coordinate? Is it typo?

Comment: yes, It was typo.

Answer (score 6):

```
data = {{0., 0.,}, {10000., 0.,}, {20000., 1.,}, {1.*10^6,}, {1.01*10^6, 4641.,}};
Most /@ data
```

> {{0., 0.}, {10000., 0.}, {20000., 1.}, {1.*10^6}, {1.01*10^6, 4641.}}

This also works

```
data[[All, {1, 2}]]
```

Comment: Thanks @Dulgerci, It is also working and simple.

Answer (score 3):

One way might be

```
data={{0.,0.,},{10000.,0.,},{20000.,1.,},{1.*10^6,},{1.01*10^6,4641.,}}
Cases[data,{a_,b_,c_}:>{a,b}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

but note that original data really is a syntax error, according to Mathematica. When Frontend hightlight something with red like this

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It means it is syntax error.

So I am not sure how you obtained the data in first place.

Comment: My assumption is those commas are really strings and the OP used `Import[..., "Table"]` but so a `DeleteCases[data, ",", Infinity]` is probably best. But I wanted him to tell us that rather than giving some useless vague question.

Comment: Thanks@Nasser It is working.